# Deserializing JSON in C# without need for container class?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Given the JSON string

```
{"MyData":{"name":"foo"}}
```

Im trying to deserialize the above JSON into a structure that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class MyData
{
   [DataMember]
   public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Unfortunately, the only way I can deserialize this (using `DataContractJsonSerializer`) is to wrap the above class as such:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class MyDataContainer
{
   [DataMember]
   public MyData MyData{get;set;}
}
```

Is it possible to decorate `MyData` with any attributes to prevent the need for the `MyDataContainer` class, or is it 'just the way it is'.

Thanks

Comment: MyData is a property, so you need the class container

Comment: Just pass {"name":"foo"} and it will deserialize into any class that has a name property.

Comment: Why is it a problem creating a container class for `MyData`? It's just a property inside your whole JSON.

Comment: May we know why you don't want to use `MyDataContainer` during  JSON de-serialization.

Comment: @Avijit Yeah sure, the provider has switched from XML to JSON - the above code worked without the container for XML, but not JSON.

Comment: Could you show us corresponding XML that worked with first code snippet?

Comment: @Victor Sure, it looks something like
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyData>
<name>foo</name>
</MyData>`

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.net to solve your problem as below

```
public class MyData
{
   public string name {get;set;}
}

var dictionary =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,MyData>>(jsonString);

var myData = dictionary["MyData"];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to xml provided by @maxp, Provider has changed own Output type, serialization startegy or serialization tool.

1. Output type is changed: so as mentioned in comment to the question, it is better to update your types in edge area.
2. Serialization strategy is changed: it might be a common pattern from their side to built artificial
   object with one field which name correspond to Output Type, in that case you can use Reflection to create Wrappers objects dynamically on the edge (do not forget cache reflection)
3. Serialization tool is changed: in that case most right thing would be asking provider for .net realization of that tool or atleast Specification of it.